# How to remove all files in one location in cordova ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic . I need to remove  all the files in my local drive location. I have tried below query . But it's not working

```
    $cordovafile.removeFile(cordova.file.documentsDirectory,"filename").then(function(success){
console log("file removed"),
function error(error){
console log("Error")
});}
```

Please suggest your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`
then inject `$cordovaFile` to your controller some thing like this

```
 app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaFile) {}
```

then try

```
$cordovaFile.removeFile(path,file)
      .then(function (success) {
        // success
      }, function (error) {
        // error
      });
```

**removeFile** only remove single file instead of that you can remove whole directory itself  by `$cordovaFile.removeDir(path,directory)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.i don't want to remove whole diretory. I just want to remove files in the path. Is it possible?

Comment: `$cordovaFile.removeFile(path,file)` this method will only remove specified file

Comment: that's fine. is any method avaliable to remove N-number of file

Comment: i think its better to create new directory and copy all the files that you needed to delete and delete that diectory take a brief look at http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

Answer (score 0):

basically you list files within a folder and then create a promises' array that delete each single file. And when deleted all of them, invoke the .then() allowing you to go on with your stuffs.

the present solution works with ionic 1.x (possibly also 2+, don't know) after having done:

install cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file.

I use it with ionic-native wrapper 
I suggest you to create a service

```
function FileSystemSrv($cordovaFile, $q)
{
    var service                         = {}; 
    service.data_storage_root           = "";
    service.resolved_data_storage_root  = "";
    //====================================================
    service.init = function(data_storage_root)
    {  
        service.data_storage_root           = data_storage_root;
        service.resolved_data_storage_root  = cordova.file[service.data_storage_root];
        return service.resolved_data_storage_root;        
    };    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    service.getExtension = function(fullname)
    {
        var arr = fullname.split(".");
        return arr[arr.length-1];
    };    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // invoke the then(), returning 1 or 0, instead of invoking the success or error callbacks
    service.existFile = function(relative_path)
    {
         return $cordovaFile.checkFile(service.resolved_data_storage_root, relative_path)
        .then(function (success){
            return 1;  
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            return $q.resolve(0);
        });        
     };


    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //return all the files contained in a folder, belonging to the [valid_extensions] formats.
    service.listFilesInDir = function(relative_path, valid_extensions)
    {
        var len_ext = 0;
        if(valid_extensions != null) len_ext = valid_extensions.length;

        return $cordovaFile.listDir(service.resolved_data_storage_root, relative_path)
        .then(function(dirs)
        {
            var len = dirs.length;
            var arr = [];
            var cnt = 0;
            for (d=0; d<len; d++)
            {
                if (!dirs[d].isDirectory)
                {
                    var insert = false;
                    if(len_ext)
                    {
                        // filter input files: show only some extensions
                        var ext = service.getExtension(dirs[d].name);
                        for (e=0; e<valid_extensions.length; e++)
                        {    
                            if( ext == valid_extensions[e])
                            {
                                insert = true; 
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else insert = true;
                    if(insert)
                    {
                        arr[cnt] = dirs[d].name;
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return arr;            
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("FileSystemSrv::listFilesInDir" + error.message);
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
    };    

    service.deleteFile = function(relative_path)
    {
        return service.existFile(relative_path)
        .then(function(exist){        
            if (exist)  return $cordovaFile.removeFile(service.resolved_data_storage_root, relative_path);
            else        return 1;
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("FileSystemSrv::deleteFile" + JSON.stringify(error));            
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
    };

    service.deleteFilesInFolder = function(relative_path, valid_extensions)
    {
        return service.listFilesInDir(relative_path, valid_extensions)
        .then(function(files)
        {
            var subPromises = [];
            for (var f=0; f<files.length; f++) 
            {
                (function(fname) 
                {
                    var subPromise  = service.deleteFile(fname)
                    subPromises.push(subPromise);
                })(relative_path + "/" + files[f]);
            }
            return $q.all(subPromises);
        })
        .then(function()
        {
            return $q.defer().resolve(1);
        })
        .catch(function(error)
        {
            console.log("FileSystemSrv::deleteFilesInFolder" + JSON.stringify(error));            
            $q.reject(error);
        });
    };
    return service;
}
main_module.service('FileSystemSrv', FileSystemSrv);
```

and then in your controller (inject the service) create this method:

```
$scope.deleteSession = function() 
{
    FileSystemSrv.init("externalRootDirectory");

    return FileSystemSrv.deleteFilesInFolder($scope.relpath, ["wav", "jpg"])       // relpath = "AFolder/asubfolder" a subfolder of externalRootDirectory
    .then(function()
    {
        // do something  
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        alert(error.message);
    });
};
```